# Teradata SQL Table Joining with Keys with Different Formats

Tags: sql, join, casting, overflow, teradata

I have a data format issue where I used the account-level identifier (accno) joining from two different tables, where it initially gave me Precision error in FLOAT type error.

```
select rcv.Product, rcv.accno, rcv.date,
            bfv.Prod_class_cd, bfv.acc_appsys_id, acc_co_no
from FINAL_RECOVERY rcv
inner join RTL_EXPSR_MTRL bfv
    on rcv.accno = bfv.accno and rcv.date = bfv.date
where rcv.Product is null
order by rcv.date;
```

So I tried to cast the accno into various other formats, but still no luck.

```
on cast(rcv.accno as int) = cast(bfv.accno as int) and rcv.date = bfv.date

on cast(rcv.accno as decimal(12,0)) = cast(bfv.accno as decimal(12,0)) and rcv.date = bfv.date

on cast(rcv.accno as char) = cast(bfv.accno as char) and rcv.date = bfv.date
```

Casting them as either int or decimals give me overflow error message, and if I cast as character I run out of spool space. Is casting the only option I have here? What would be your suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: My suggestion?  Fix the data so the keys are the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

When you get a *float precision error* you seem to have one numeric column and one VarChar with more than 15 digits in it.

```
-- INTEGERs only got up to 10 digits = less than 15 = numeric overflow
cast(rcv.accno as int) = cast(bfv.accno as int)
-- decimal(12,0) got 12 digits = less than 15 = numeric overflow
cast(rcv.accno as decimal(12,0)) = cast(bfv.accno as decimal(12,0))
-- cast as char = cast as CHAR(1) = Teradata silently truncating to a single digit
-- = join is similar to a Cross Join = no more spool space
cast(rcv.accno as char) = cast(bfv.accno as char)
```

Keep the numeric column as is and cast the other column to the same data type. This will work unless you got bad data, then use `TO_NUMBER(accno)` or  TD15.10's `TRYCAST`, both will return NULL for bad data and thus exclude the row.

Comment: Thanks. Currently not on TD15.10 but to_number seems to resolve this.